# Using same directive with different value in the same view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two tabs, each tab contains a set of thumbnails which I have set as a directive. Tab is also coming via a directive, and thumbnails too. The data to be pushed into the thumbnail is stored in an constant file. But each tabs thumbnails data is different. How do I implement that?

For setting tabs and thumbnail:

```
<tabset> <tab heading="{{heading.title}}" id="heading1" set-thumb="setThumbnail(arg)">
        <thumbnail></thumbnail>
        </tab> <tab heading="{{heading1.title}}" id="heading2" set-thumb="setThumbnail(arg)">
        <thumbnail></thumbnail>
        </tab> </tabset>
```

Thumbnail HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 20px;">
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="data in thumbnailDetails">
    <div class="thumbnail-sim">
        <img src="resources/images/Sim-thumbnail.png" alt="sim"
            class="thumbnail-img">
        <div class="thumbnail-caption">
            <div class="thumbnail-name">{{ data.name }}</div>
            <div class="thumbnail-date">{{ data.time }}</div>
            <div class="thumbnail-details">
                <a href="#" type="button" style="text-decoration: none;">{{ data.details }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Thumbnail directive:

```
angular.module('thumbnailDirectiveModule', [])
.directive('thumbnail', function() {
return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'UI/templates/thumbnail.html'
    };
});
```

service part method:

```
s.getThumbnail = function(thisId){
    if(thisId === 'heading1'){
        return thumbnailDetails1;
    }else if (thisId === 'heading2'){
        return thumbnailDetails2;
    }

};
```

Tab directive:

```
angular.module('tabsDirectiveModule', [])
.directive('tab', function() {
return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div role="tabpanel" ng-show="active" ng-transclude></div>',
      require: '^tabset',
      scope: {
        heading: '@',
        id: '@',
                setThumb: '&'
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, tabsetCtrl) {
        scope.active = false;
        tabsetCtrl.addTab(scope, attr.id); 
              }
    };
})
.directive('tabset', function() {
return {
restrict: 'E',
transclude: true,
scope: { },
templateUrl: 'UI/templates/tabset.html',
bindToController: true,
controllerAs: 'tabset',
controller: function() {
  var self = this;
  self.tabs = [];
  self.addTab = function addTab(tab, id) {
      tab.setThumb({arg: id});
      self.tabs.push(tab);
       if(self.tabs.length === 1) {
        tab.active = true;
      }
    };
  self.select = function(selectedTab) {
      angular.forEach(self.tabs, function(tab) {
        if(tab.active && tab !== selectedTab) {
          tab.active = false;
        }
      });
      selectedTab.active = true;

    };
}
};
});
```

Comment: Post your current implementation, plz

Comment: Have a look at [Directive Scope isolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) in the angular guide

Comment: @MarcoS..check my question now

Comment: @Rhumborl.. I have read that. but in my case, both tabs are getting same thumbnail data

Comment: Directives isn't the tool for this : check `ui-router` for this. To be more precise check either views or nestd state for your need. If the data in your thymnail present different part of the same dataset, you can go for using ng-model along with your directive.